# Post json formatted data on server swift

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I am new to json and swift
I want to send json formatted data and header on server
Here is Code

```
    "Destination":{"ContactPerson":"Garry Jackson","Address":{"PostCode":"4104","StreetAddress":"Bay View","Suburb":"BAY VIEW","BuildingName":"15 Le Quesne Rd","City":"NAPIER","CountryCode":"NZ"},"PhoneNumber":"027 3356871","Email":"jacko.bv@xtra.co.nz","Name":"Garry Jackson"} 


    let parameters = [
        "Packages" : ["Length" : Length, "Type" : "", "Kg" : Weight, "Height" : Height, "Width" : Width, "Name" : SkuName],
        "issignaturerequired" : true,
        "Outputs":["LABEL_PNG_100X175"],
        "DeliveryReference":86882,
        "Destination":["ContactPerson":self.CustomerFirstname,
                       "Address":["PostCode":self.PostalCode,"StreetAddress":self.Address1,"Suburb":self.City,"BuildingName":"ABC","City":self.City,"CountryCode":"AU"],
                       "PhoneNumber":9998406081,"Email":self.CustomerEmail,"Name":self.CustomerFirstname],
        "PrintToPrinter":true,
        "SendTrackingEmail":"",
        "Commodities":[["UnitKg":1.0000,"Currency":"NZD","Country":"NZ","Units":1,"Description":"Drums Drum Accessories Drum Bags","UnitValue":44.0],["UnitKg":1.0000,"Currency":"NZD","Country":"NZ","Units":1,"Description":"Drums Drum Accessories Drum Bags","UnitValue":44.0]],
        "DeliveryInstructions":"None"
    ]

    let headers = [
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Access_Key":"Key"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://api.omniparcel.com/labels/printcheapestcourier", headers: headers, parameters:  parameters).responseJSON {
        response in
        print(response)
        let json = JSON(response.data!) //SwiftyJSON
    }
```

How to post this data in swift

Comment: i use OmniParcel Print service api. Anyone use it ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for the HTTPRequest and [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to parse the json returned. Or use `NSURLSession` and deserialize the `JSON` in swift. (You can search S.O. for some examples)

```
    let parameters = [
        "Packages": [
            "length": myLengthVariable,
            "type": "kg"
           //add parameters here
        ]
    ]

    let headers = [
    "Content-Type: application/json"
    //add addition headers here

    ]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.omniparcel.com/labels/printcheapestcourier", headers: headers, parameters:  parameters).responseJSON {
 response in
           let json = JSON(response.data) //SwiftyJSON
         //Do whatever you want with the json here

    }
```

Comment: but this error occurs ''JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length"

Comment: try `let json = JSON(data: response.data!)` if that doesnt work check your url and parameters.

Comment: Well you can read more about the usage here https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#usage or check your links to ensure everything is correct. (Also try printing out the response received to help your debugging)

Comment: i think my parameters are not set properly can you tell how to set json array in parameters

Comment: Destination Parameter contains array

Comment: Your params look correct. What's being returned by the `response` object?

Comment: FAILURE: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6006 "JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length.}

Comment: Change `Access_key` to `aftership-api-key` if you already havent

Comment: i don't have aftership-api-key i have only omni parcel print agent api key

Comment: sorry i was reading the wrong api documentation lool. Im not to sure whats wrong. Except the api doesnt return a JSON but  xml. Could you post a link to the documentation?

Comment: here is link of pdf https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlinm0hjgb11fyo/Omni%20Parcel%20API%20Spec.pdf?dl=0

Comment: try setting your heads to `access_key:[access_key_for_site_account]Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8` as stated in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

you can use Alamofire for this.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

```
 var parameters : [String : AnyObject] = [
        "PackageA" : [["Length" : length, "Type" : type, "Kg" : kg, "Height" : height, "Width" : width, "Name" : name]],
        "issignaturerequired" : "true",
        //Put all your other JSON properties here
    ]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://api.omniparcel.com/labels/printcheapestcourier", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print(JSON);

            }
    }
```

Comment: i also used your code  
but this error occurs ''JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length"